# Is it useful to setup RAID0 on laptop?

Tags: performance, lvm, raid, mdadm

I have a Dell laptop, which I am going to replace the CD-ROM hub with a HDD. I am thinking if I setup a **RAID0** on my original HDD and the new HDD, would I have some I/O performance improvement?

Theoretically, there will be some improvement. But I would like to know how much it will be? If it just *kinda of improved*, I don't think it worth the effort. Especially, I need to move my data around to do the converting.

Comment: If this is a modular bay kind of deal (as a lot of Dells are), then I'd avoid a RAID0 just because I might accidentally disconnect the second HDD at some point.

Comment: The speeds of the drives are more or less added.. whether that is worth it or not is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are usually two main metrics of disc subsystem effectiveness:

- Bandwidth (how many data per certain amount of time it can read or write)
- Latency (how long does it take to get answer for a certain disc request)

As a rule of thumb, RAID0 would have:

- Bandwidth = approximately sum of bandwidth of all drives
- Latency = little worse than average of all drives

So, given normal laptop tasks and regular laptop HDDs (usually 5400 RPM SATA ones), I'd say that for interactive tasks latency is much more important than bandwidth, and you won't get major improvements here. If an application makes like 100 sequential requests that each takes like 50 ms, it won't matter if you would have RAID0 - this action would still take 5 seconds.

RAID0 would slightly help if you regularly deal with major bandwidth-hogging stuff, like copying around large files or processing heavy data streams. However, the only real-life interactive desktop application I could imagine for such usage pattern is video editing.

Looking at the downsides, note that stability of 2 HDDs in RAID0 goes down *a lot*. Typical RAID0 applications at servers department is the first-tier caching or something like that, when your data has absolutely no value (usually because it could be trivially recreated).

So, bottom line: probably no, it won't unless you have any bandwidth-heavy applications like video editing for your laptop.